# Change first and last elements of strings or lists inside a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list

I have a dataframe like this:

```
data = {
    'name': ['101 blueberry 2023', '102 big cat 2023', '103 small white dog 2023'],
    'number': [116, 118, 119]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

output:

```
                       name  number          
0        101 blueberry 2023     116         
1          102 big cat 2023     118           
2  103 small white dog 2023     119
```

I would like to change the first and last numbers in the `name` column. For example, the first number in `name` to the number in the `number` column, and the last number in `name` to '2024'. So finally it would look like:

```
                       name  number   
0        116 blueberry 2024     116          
1          118 big cat 2024     118          
2  119 small white dog 2024     119
```

I have tried splitting `name` into a list and changing the first and last elements of the list.

```
df['name_pieces'] = df['name'].split(' ')
df
```

output:

```
                      name  number                     name_pieces
0        101 blueberry 2023     116          [101, blueberry, 2023]
1          102 big cat 2023     118           [102, big, cat, 2023]
2  103 small white dog 2023     119  [103, small, white, dog, 2023]
```

I can access the first item of the lists using `.str`, but I cannot change the item.

```
df['name_pieces'].str[0]
```

output:

```
0    101
1    102
2    103
```

but trying to assign the first value of the list gives an error

```
df['name_pieces'].str[0] = df['number']
```

output:

```
TypeError: 'StringMethods' object does not support item assignment
```

How can I replace the first and last value of `name` inside this dataframe?

Comment: Do you want the `'name_pieces'` column to eventually be a string (and using a list just for indexing) ?

Comment: Yes, I'll be joining it into a string again.

Comment: @edge-case Please [edit] the question to mention that. Pandas isn't great with nested data (as you've noticed), so this is an [XY problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832)

Comment: thanks @wjandrea, I just edited to highlight my final goal, which is actually editing the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't bother with the lists. You can just extract the part of the strings you want and join the other parts.

```
df.assign(name=
    df['number'].astype(str)
    + df['name'].str.extract(r'( .* )', expand=False)
    + '2024'
)
```

```
                       name  number
0        116 blueberry 2024     116
1          118 big cat 2024     118
2  119 small white dog 2024     119
```

This regex gets the longest part of the string surrounded by spaces, i.e the part between the first space and last space.

---

Here's a variation if you'd rather think about `name` primarily:

```
df.assign(name=
    df['name'].str.extract(r'( .* )', expand=False)
    .radd(df['number'].astype(str))
    .add('2024')
)
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the regex, hahaha regex is always hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df["name_pieces"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: [x["number"], *x["name_pieces"][1:-1], 2024], axis=1
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                       name  number                     name_pieces
0        101 blueberry 2023     116          [116, blueberry, 2024]
1          102 big cat 2023     118           [118, big, cat, 2024]
2  103 small white dog 2023     119  [119, small, white, dog, 2024]
```

Answer (score 1):

With single regex replacement without having to preliminary `.str.split(' ')` and without using `df.apply`:

```
df['name_pieces'] = (
    df['number'].astype(str)
    + df['name'].str.replace(r'^(\d+)(.+) \d+$', r'\2 2024', regex=True))
```

---

```
                       name  number               name_pieces
0        101 blueberry 2023     116        116 blueberry 2024
1          102 big cat 2023     118          118 big cat 2024
2  103 small white dog 2023     119  119 small white dog 2024
```

Comment: interesting idea to use regex instead of `.split(' ')`

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

use `replace` with regex

```
df['name'] = df['name'].replace({'^\d+':'', '2023$':'2024'}, regex=True)\
                       .radd(df['number'].astype('str'))
```

`df`:

```
    name                        number
0   116 blueberry 2024          116
1   118 big cat 2024            118
2   119 small white dog 2024    119
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, based on [`pandas.Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to split the column `name` by the first space (`n=1`):

```
(df.assign(name = df['number'].astype('str').add(' ')
           .add(df['name'].str.split('\s', n=1, expand=True)[1])
           .str.replace('\d+$', '2024', regex=True)))
```

Output:

```
                       name  number
0        116 blueberry 2024     116
1          118 big cat 2024     118
2  119 small white dog 2024     119
```